# Using hook to alter panel plugin block form

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm attempting to add items to every block form including the core ones from my custom module. I figured I could use the mymodule_form_formid_alter hook. And I'm assuming that block_form is the form id for the block form.

My module is called ablecore. And inside my ablecore.module file I have.

```
function ablecore_form_block_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    $form['ablecore_style'] = [
        'background' => [
            '#type' => 'details',
            '#title' => $this->t('Background'),
            '#open' => FALSE,
            'color' => [
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#options' => [
                    '' => $this->t('Default'),
                    'bg-orange' => $this->t('Orange'),
                    'bg-grey' => $this->t('Grey'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

However none of these form items appear on any of the block forms. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code works fine for me, all I changed was the name of the module and the details element with select inside appears at the bottom of every block form. Make sure the module's enabled and caches have been cleared

Comment: In fact I also removed the references to `$this->t()` as you're in a function not a class method and those would produce fatal errors. The fact you haven't seen a "The website encountered an unexpected error" message suggests the hook hasn't been registered yet

Comment: Yeah it looks like you're right. The hook never fires. Not sure why. Is there anything I need other than the .module file with that in it and the .info file? Also I'm sure the module is enabled the cache cleared.

Comment: It's .info.yml for Drupal 8 but yeah those are the only 2 files you need (in theory)

Comment: @Clive I think I see an issue. The code works when placing a block in the block layout section but when using page manager and panels the fields don't appear. Is there a special hook I need to use when using panels?

Comment: @Clive also if you want. Since this question was different enough, I went ahead and created a new post for it. If you know the answer you can post it here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247802/hook-form-block-form-alter-works-on-block-layout-form-but-not-on-block-form-in-p