# HOOK_form_block_form_alter works on Block Layout Form but not on Block Form in Page Manager and Panels

Tags: 8, blocks, hooks

My ultimate goal is to apply an extra set of style options to any block including the core blocks. So I created a custom module with this code in the .module file

```
function mymodule_form_block_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    $form['mymodule_style'] = [
        'background' => [
            '#type' => 'details',
            '#title' => $this->t('Background'),
            '#open' => FALSE,
            'color' => [
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#options' => [
                    '' => $this->t('Default'),
                    'bg-orange' => $this->t('Orange'),
                    'bg-grey' => $this->t('Grey'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

And it appears that it works in /structure/blocklayout but I use page manager and panels for my block placement and those options don't appear there. Is there another hook related specifically to panel plugin forms? Also if there is, where in the code are these hooks defined, so I can easily discover this for any module in the future?